# Pop up a form when a specific field value is choosen in the combobox in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box in the "Form A" where field values are poupulated from another table in Access 2007. "Form A" is of datasheet type and there are 3 hidden columns. I try to make a Pop-up form("Form B") that will open up when a specific value(e.g. "RAIL") is selected in the combobox and use "Form B" to fill the hidden columns values. 
I try:

```
Private Sub Combo36_Change()
 If Combo36.Value = "RAIL" Then
      DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Received"
  End If
End Sub
```

But that doesn't work. Any help is appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Does nothing at all happen? Can you put a break point in and step through the code to see what it's doing? In any case I would suggest using the AfterUpdate event.

Comment: Nothing happens! I'll try AfterUpdate event.

Comment: It's working after "Enable" the content that are disabled due to "security reason"...

Comment: Ah yes, that would do it!